# Some spaces not showing when displaying units

Tags: math-mode

When I use the following expression:

```
p_{2}=\dfrac {0,75\cdot 10^{5} Pa \cdot 0,12 m^{3}}{0,06 m^{3}}=1,5\cdot 10^{5} Pa
```

It displays as follows:

[image]

Looks like Pa is separated from the quantity, while m^3 is not.

How can I force the white spaces?

Using WP Quicklatex with:

```
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Three observations: 1) there is a deicated package to typeset units (`siunitx`); 2) there indeed should be a thin unbreakable space inserted between numbers and units; 3) units should be typeset in upright characters and certainly not in math mode, with a letterspacing different from the letterspacing of text.

Comment: Off-topic: The `mathpazo` package provides Palatino text and math fonts --- no need to load the `palatino` package as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As very justly pointed out in @Bernard comment we can use the `\SI` command from the `siunitx` package. However we have to adjust some options to get a comma as decimal separator an a dot as an exponent multiplier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[
  exponent-product = \cdot, 
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  ]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\[
p_{2}=\frac {\SI{0.75e5}{Pa} \times \SI{0,12} {m^{3}}}{\SI{0,06 }{m^{3}}}=\SI{1,5e5} {Pa}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. It is more idiomatic -- to the `siunitx` package, that is to write `\SI{0.75e5}{\pascal}`,  `\SI{0,12}{\meter\cubed}` and `\SI{0,06}{\meter\cubed}` instead of `\SI{0.75e5}{Pa}`,  `\SI{0,12}{m^{3}}`, and `\SI{0,06 }{m^{3}}`. The package does manage to parse the latter three expressions correctly, but you're missing out on a nice opportunity to write out the *meaning* of the material instead of its symbolic representation.

Comment: @Mico perhaps but I don't think there is a great visual difference and I find that writing just `m^3` is faster than `\meter\cubed`

Comment: I guess I didn't express myself clearly. My apologies. For sure, `\SI{0,06}{\meter\cubed}` and `\SI{0,06 }{m^{3}}` produce the *exact same output*; there is absolutely no visual difference. The point of writing `\meter` rather than `m` in the second argument of `\SI` is to emphasize -- in the *input*, not the output -- the *meaning* of the material to be typeset.

Comment: Thank you, this looks much more professional. Do you recommend any tool to convert handwritten math to well structured laTeX? I use the myscript web demo https://webdemo.myscript.com/views/math/ The thing is, I want to write a lot of math, and I prefer to automate the LaTeXing process as much as possible, while keeping good practices.

Comment: @mico May be but I am not sure since when I type `\SI{3}{m^3}`  and read it again after a few months I will know exactly that it is meant *three cubed meter*. I think that it is a matter of taste :).

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda Taking an example from the `siunitx` manual, like you (I presume), I don't find `\si{\kilo\gram\metre\per\square\second}` particularly easier to read than `\si{kg.m/s^2}`. That said, the `siunitx` manual does give an objective advantage of the more verbose approach: “By altering the settings used by the package, the same input can yield
a variety of different output formats. For example, the `\per` macro can give reciprocal powers, slashes or be used to construct units as fractions.” (for those who care!)